# python coding for a word to convert number?

Tags: python, text, encoding, numbers, cpu-word

I want to type a word to take output as number.
I expect it to write numbers according to the sequence number in the alphabet.
For example, when I write the word "add" as input to the program, I want to see it as output 1 4 4
and when I enter a number, I want it to show me letters. can you help me?

```
data=input("type a word : ")
harfler = "abcçdefgğhıijklmnoöprşstuüvyz"
output = []
if data[0].isnumeric():
    data = data.split(' ')
    for num in data:
        print(f"{harfler[int(num)-1]}", end='')
else: 
    for harf in data:
        print(f"{harfler.index(harf)+1} ", end='')

print()
```

Edited: last code is above. Finally, I want the program to not end without issuing an exit command.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this answers your question.

```
letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
output = []
for l in data:
    if l.isnumeric():
        output.append( letters[int(l)] )
    else:
        output.append( str(letters.index(l)) )

 print(' '.join(output))
```

Comment: thank you for your helping I prefer to starting first letter is 1 not 0 and lastly I want to add to number convert to letter when trying to "add" word convert to 0 4 4 okey but i want to convert it 1 5 5 and when i writing 1,5,5 or 1 5 5 should convert to "add" one more thing it not will be end until i will close it